# PhantomJS + Selenium , How to se user agent for links that open in new window?

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to click on a link which opens in new tab (target="_blank") using selenium and phantomjs but the problem is that when phantomjs opens the link, it doesn't set the user agent defined for it using DesiredCapabilities. If the link opens in the current window everything is ok but as soon as it opens in a new window, user agent is the default one !

How can i set user agent globally ? (BTW i'm using python)

Comment: Might be better suited as a selenium github issue if you can provide a full code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some investigation, I found that the problem seem to be from ghost driver. So i checked ghost driver github and found the issue is there from 2013 and there is a temporary solution for that. I write the solution here as it was no result of github issue in google searches (https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/273) :

> Guaranteed solution for links target = "_blank" and window.open - set phantomjs.page.customHeaders.User-Agent in desiredCapabilities. In my case (window.open) may open a new window with the "about:blank" url, then find it in the handles array to activate and surf.

So while it is not recommended to set userAgent in custom headers in selenium documents but it is currently the only way to set userAgent globally so it doesn't change in new windows.

Comment: The User-Agent even doesn't work so much setting it from internal Javascript. PhantomJS is far away to be a complete browser, as it dones't follow lot of common behaviors. If you don't have much problem with ram usage, switch to Firefox + xephyr/vnc. PhantomJS has at least 3 big flaws (user-agent on certain functions, iframe rendering and focus inability).

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. working for me.

`GetEval("window.open('Url')");
               var winHandle = _sel.UnderlyingWebDriver.WindowHandles;
                _sel.UnderlyingWebDriver.SwitchTo().Window(winHandle[1]);
                _sel.UnderlyingWebDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();`

Comment: How is this related to my problem ?! Your code opens a url in new window and switches to it and maximizes the window !

Comment: Okay but if you go through my code you will see now you are able to work on new window.